# Estimate joint probability of two dependent variable

Tags: probability, python, joint-distribution, mutual-information, numpy

I've a dataset created in the following way:

- The input of the system is a 8 bit binary number ranging from $x_1$= 0000
  0000 to $x_N$ = 1111 1111
- For every input i've read the output of the system (which is continuous) and a vector of size 2, for example $y_1$= [0.47  , 0.56] is associated to $x{_1}$ and so on untill $y_N$ to $x{_N}$

I need to find $p(x)$,$p(y)$ and $p(x,y)$ in order to find the Mutual Information using the following formula:

[image]

Is it correct to assume that $p(x)$ has a probability of: $p_1(x) = \frac{1}{N.InputSamples}$ ?
In order to find $p_2(x)$ I've discretized the output using Nbins, counting the occurrences of each value and divide all for the sum. But what about $p(x,y)$? I was thinking about to use the numpy function `histogram2d` ([as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687458/how-to-calculate-probabilities-using-numpy-histogram-and-then-use-it-for-calcula)) but it gives me an error because the input and output have got different shape.